# How to use SharedPreferences in RecyclerView.Adapter in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-recyclerview

This is need for DarkMode

I need to load my colorMode var from SharedPreferences in RecyclerView.Adapter, but IDE marks "this" or "application" like an error

where can I insert those code without any errors

```
    val preferences = *this*.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = preferences.edit()
    var colorMode = false
    colorMode = preferences.getBoolean("ThemeMode", false)
```

Comment: You should pass the context to the adapter, cast it to an activity and use it in place of this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers to the adapter and not the the `context`.

You should call `getSharedPreferences()` on the `context` of your app.

If this code is inside the `ViewHolder`, use this:

```
val preferences = view.getContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Best